# Как сделать select и сразу insert в другую таблицу , другой базы python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, запрос, pymysql

подскажите, как мне из запроса select что я сделал, к разным базам , вставить в мою новую базу в таблицу krd? При этом, хочу , что бы то что уже было вставлено до этого, не вставлялось заново, а просто обновлялись изменения в полях. Ниже , код не работает на вставку, может кто объяснить, как это реализовать

```
   db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="password")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT `nova`.`instances`.`created_at` ," \
          "`nova`.`instances`.`updated_at` , " \
          "`keystone`.`nonlocal_user`.`name` , " \
          "`keystone`.`project`.`name` ," \
          "`nova`.`instances`.`power_state` ," \
          "`nova`.`instances`.`vm_state` ," \
          "substring(replace(`keystone`.`user`.`extra`, '\"}','') , '12') , " \
          "`nova`.`instances`.`host`, " \
          "`nova`.`instances`.`display_name`," \
          "`nova`.`instances`.`uuid`" \
          "FROM `nova`.`instances` " \
          "JOIN `keystone`.`nonlocal_user` on `nova`.`instances`.`user_id` = `keystone`.`nonlocal_user`.`user_id`" \
          "JOIN `keystone`.`user` on `nova`.`instances`.`user_id` = `keystone`.`user`.`id`" \
          "JOIN `keystone`.`project` on `nova`.`instances`.`project_id` = `keystone`.`project`.`id`" \
          "WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),`nova`.`instances`.`created_at`) > 365 AND `nova`.`instances`.`vm_state` = `deleted`"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        created_at, updated_at, nonlocal_user, project,power_state,extra,host,display_name = row
        cursor_table2.execute("INSERT INTO `vmremove.krd` VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,'%s'%s,%s,%s)" % (created_at, updated_at, nonlocal_user, project, power_state,extra, host, display_name ))
```

Comment: Если Вы хотите обновлять данные, почему используете INSERT, а не UPDATE?

Comment: Другая база - на этом же сервере?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич потому что их пока нету, в базе vmremove.krd

Comment: @Akina да, пока да, но в дальнейшем будут разнесены

Comment: @user405396 понятно. Тогда нужно делать 2 SQL запроса. Первым в "новой базе" надо выбрать pk тех данных, что уже были вставлены. Их обновить SQL запросом UPDATE. Оставшиеся данные сделать INSERT. Как вариант.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич а можно пример? У меня как бы главная база nova.instance , там данные меняются, и они по определенным фильтрам , должны попадать в мою новую базу, причем если уже к примеру uuid уже есть в базе, его надо обновить, а не добавить новой строкой

Comment: @user405396 По идее описанное мной выше можно сделать одним  сложным SQL запросом. Но если речь не идёт о hiload и частом использовании - я бы разбил задачу на два запроса.

Comment: @user405396 какой у Вас первичный ключ в базах? Есть уникальные поля?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич UUID , вот это может быть уникальное поле для связи

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич *По идее описанное мной выше можно сделать одним сложным SQL запросом.* Товарищ же сказал, что "в дальнейшем базы будут разнесены на разные серверы". И запрос перестанет работать.

Comment: *в дальнейшем будут разнесены* Будут ли они доступны друг другу? Как насчёт включить на них FEDERATED Engine?

Comment: @Alkin доступны будут, но вот включить я ничего не смогу, просто надо забрать данные и внести изменения

Comment: Я к тому, что гонять тонны байтов с сервера на клиента и обратно - не самое умное занятие (речь явно же не о паре килобайтов). Если доступно - выгрузить на первом сервере в CSV, перегнать на второй сервер (если нет прямого доступа к файловой системе), и там загрузить. А программа пусть только рулит этим процессом (а если операция регулярная, то выгрузкой/загрузкой может заняться Event Scheduler, аплоадом файла, если он нужен - Cron, а программа так и вовсе не нужна).

Comment: @Akina Парни, а можно код?:)

Comment: @Akina, я так не хочу делать, я хочу взять из базы.таблицы1 , базы.таблица2 , базы2.тиблица3, вставить значения в в базу.таблица5, как мне это запросом сделать? типа того results = cursor.fetchall()
for elem in results:
    sql1 = "INSERT INTO `vmremover`.`krd` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`username`,`project`,`vm_state`,`power_state`,`email`,`status_send`,`host`,`vmname`,`uuid`,`statusremove`) VALUES ('elem[1]','elem[2)"
    cursor.execute(sql1)
    db.commit()
только что бы работало

Answer (score 2):

Возможная реализация.

**Этап 1:** данные на сервере-источнике форматируются в вид, удобный для загрузки на целевом сервере, и записываются в текстовый CSV-файл запросом [SELECT ... INTO Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html):

```sql
SELECT {список вывода, поля/выражения}
FROM {список таблиц-источников}
INTO OUTFILE {полный путь к CSV-файлу выгрузки}
{опции выгрузки}
```

Если таблицы вообще имеют одинаковую структуру, и преобразование не требуется, так и вовсе

```sql
TABLE {таблица-источник}
INTO OUTFILE {полный путь к CSV-файлу выгрузки}
{опции выгрузки}
```

Запрос выполняется либо управляющей программой, либо заданием [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).

**Этап 2:**
Файл перемещается с сервера-источника на сервер-приёмник.

Используется управляющая программа либо задание штатного либо стороннего планировщика ОС (cron, например), протокол передачи определяется возможностями систем (файловый доступ, FTP  и т.п).

Если каталог выгрузки доступен с сервера-приёмника, этап не требуется.

**Этап 3:**
Данные на сервере-приёмнике загружаются в таблицу (с обновлением существующих записей).

Вариант 1: сначала данные загружаются во временную таблицу (с использованием [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)), затем обновляются запросом [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) либо [REPLACE INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html).

Вариант 2: сразу выполняется обновление одним из вышеуказанных запросов, данные получаются непосредственно из CSV-файла с использованием [CSV Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html).

Запрос выполняется либо управляющей программой, либо заданием Event Scheduler.